# In db https is used for home, but in backend http is used and cannot be edited

Tags: homepage, options, https

I switched my web from http to https by using "Better search and replace" and everything worked fine - at first sight.

All resources were deliverd via https and the Firefox showed a green lock. But when now uploading a new image I saw that it will be delivered via http.

I immediatle checked my db but in options/home and options/siteurl **the entry is https**. In wp-config I also use define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);. And now the curious thing: When checking the WordPress Address (URL) under "Settings/General" there is a http-entry which cannot be edited.

**[image: The db says https but the backend says http]**

**The db says https but the backend says http...** I´m really helpless... What can I do?

Comment: Are you setting the URL in `wp-config.php`? Is this a multisite install? Did you configure your server to redirect insecure requests to HTTPS?

Comment: Home and siteurl are not set in the wp-config.php and it‘s no multisite install. But I redirect all http requests and non—www to https://www in my htaccess (as in most of my WP installs). I already replaced all entries in the db from http to https via Better Earch And Replace, but still the same problem... :(

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to hardcode the value of the "Wordpress Address (URL)" and "Site Address(URL)" options within your *wp-config.php* file. When the value of either field is hardcoded this way, it takes precedence over the respective value set in the database. This is why you cannot edit the field via the Wordpress Admin Page ( the value is hardcoded ).

My suggestion to resolving your issue is this:

1) Open your *wp-config.php* file 
2) Look for a line of code similar to the one below

```
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');
```

3) delete it

That's it! You should now be able to edit the "Wordpress Address (URL)" from the admin page.

Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php

Comment: Home and siteurl are not set in the wp-config.php. That´s why I don´t understand that in WP backend the field is uneditable...?

Comment: After some testing on my end, it looks like it's also possible to define the `HOME` and `SITEURL` outside of `wp-config.php` via the same method as the one in my answer. 

The next step would then be to check your plugins and theme. First check to see whether the site and home urls are set in the `functions.php` file of your theme. If it's not, then you can move on to checking whether it is set by within one of your plugins by disabling all of them.

Comment: Yes, I´m afraid I have to check all my plugins for bugfixing... But thanks for your try...

Comment: I tried to bugfix it and deactivated all plugins, changed the theme to twentyseven, searched the database and also made a search through all files in the wp folder. But i found nothing! There´s still http instead of https. And I still cannot edit the field.

Any idea what to do now? I´m really desperate :)

Comment: Try hard-coding the new value of the Wordpress Address (URL) by adding `define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com');` to your wp-config.php file. If the change doesn't take effect then that indicates to me that this the change might be hardcoded at a point in time earlier than when wp-config.php is read - meaning that it might be set in a WP core file like index.php or wp-blog-header.php. If it DOES take effect then it might be defined at some point in time after wp-config.php is loaded but before theme files take effect ( e.g wp-settings.php ).

Comment: How did you search through all files? Did you manually open up each file and search for it, or did you perform a string search using a tool like [grep](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/grep-command-in-unixlinux/) ? If you performed a string search, what specific string did you search for?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god, call me noob of the month... ;)

The problem was in fact a small line of code at the bottom of the wp-config.php which I always use in my WP webs to change the content folder's name.

I changed it and now it works.